# Generate multiple output files starting from a single "seed" file

Tags: matlab, object-oriented-analysis

Good Morning everybody,

it's sometime I wonder if it is possible to do something close to what I'm gonna describe by means of Matlab:

1. Using an external tool (i.e. Ansys, Abaqus or other software) I engender a "seed" listed (file extension .inp, .db or others) file which will be used as reference for the next steps;
2. Starting from this seed listed file, I would like to get, let's say, 200 similar project files, containing some slight variations compared to the seed: I mean, for instance, simulation time or any other characteristic.

I will give a short example: I'm currently working on Bladed, software perfoming aero-elastic simulation for wind energy applications; Blade gives me, for instance, the chance to generate turbulent wind fields. The seed code would be the one shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<BladedProject version="4.2.0.46">
    <BladedData dataFormat="project">
        <![CDATA[
VERSION 4.2.0.46
MULTIBODY    1
CALCULATION 3
OPTIONS 0
PROJNAME    
DATE    
ENGINEER    
NOTES   ""
PASSWORD    
MSTART WINDND
SPMODEL 7
NLAT    31
NVER    45
LATDIM   150
VERDIM   220
LONGLS   340.2
LATLS    42.1482
VERTLS   42.1467
XLV  113.4
YLV  66.3117
ZLV  33.1546
XLW  27.72
YLW  25.228
ZLW  50.4542
LAMBDA1  0
CohScale     340.2
COHDEC   12
SCALE    0
GAMMA    0
YDIML    0
N2  0
YDIMS    0
K1MIN    3
LENGTH   1830
STEP     .2233905
UBAR     3
SEED    3
OUTFILE l:\02_turb_dev\50-1\loads\50-1_D116_Validation_adapted_to_AV07\wind\DLC1-2_Kaimal\s1\3.wnd
DIAM     0
HUBHT    0
TURBHTTYPE   0
TURBBOTTOM   0
GUSTAVT  0
GUSTSPEED    0
TOLERANCE    0
DLONGMIN     0
DLONGMAX     0
Z0MIN    0
Z0MAX    0
MAXITER  14
MAXSEED  100
NFILES   1
UseWindShear     0
UseShearToGust   0
WVMODEL 0
MATCHFILE   ''
SPACING  0
SAMPLEFREQ   0
MEANSPEED    0
ILAT     0
IVERT    0
GUSTMETHOD   0
DLONG    0
ILAT     0
IVERT    0
LONGGUST     0
LATGUST  0
VERTGUST     0
iLONGGUST    0
iLATGUST     0
iVERTGUST    0
PEAKINESS    0
MAXFRAN  0
MEND

0WINDND
        ]]>
    </BladedData>
</BladedProject>
```

By means of matlab I would like to be able to generate similar project files for different wind speeds and random seeds (UBAR,SEED) and to save these files in a predetermined sub-folder.

Finally, I only would be glad to know if any of you has a clue/advice to give me.
Then, it will be my task to find out a proper architecture for coding.

I thank you all in advance for supporting.

Best regards,
Francesco

Comment: What you describe is certainly possible, but the vagueness of your question invites vague answers such as *What you describe is certainly possible*  Can you be a lot more specific ?

Comment: Please put a clear question in your text (ending with a question mark '?'). Also, what have you already tried? What didn't work?

Comment: the question is: By means of matlab I would like to be able to generate similar project files for different wind speeds and random seeds (UBAR,SEED) and to save these files in a predetermined sub-folder. Finally, I only would be glad to know if any of you has a clue/advice to give me? I haven't tried yet, I'm just willing to know if this could be possible in matlab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here are some bits and pieces of an answer, read more about the functions used in the Matlab documentation.  The code below is only an example, but you shouldn't have any trouble expanding it. This code will write 5 files with `UBAR` values `1..5`.  I'll suppose that, at the start of execution, your current working directory is a suitable place for those 5 files to reside, at least temporarily

```
for ubar = 1:5  %using the name of the variable as the iteration variable here
    fname = ['bladefile' num2str(ubar) '.txt'] % filenames will be bladefile1.txt etc
    fid = fopen(fname,'w') % open the file for writing, keep the file id for later reference
    fprintf(fid, '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>\n<BladedProject version="4.2.0.46">\n    <BladedData dataFormat="project">\n      <![CDATA[\n')
```

This `fprintf` call writes to the output file (using the file id `fid`); it writes your XML header.  Note the embedded `\n`s which will be turned into new lines in the output file.

```
    fprintf(fid, 'VERSION 4.2.0.46\n') % note, again, the trailing newline so the next line of output starts on a new line
    ...
    fprintf(fid, 'ubar %i\n', ubar)
```

This call to `fprintf` writes the string `ubar` to the file, then the `%i` indicates that an integer will be written, and the value of that integer will be taken from the variable `ubar`.

And so on until the end of the loop

```
    fclose(fid)
end % and loop around
```

This should get you started and, if your aim is only to write a set of output files once, is good enough for throwaway use.

If you expect to re-use the code do as you would in any programming language and wrap it up into a function.  For example, you could write a function which takes a value for `ubar` and a value for `seed` as inputs and writes the file, something like this;

```
for ubar = 1:5
    for seed = 1:7
        write_inp_file(ubar,seed)
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This could be a valuable starting point. Usually I will have a folder structure like this: wind --> DLC-X-Y --> seedN where DLC is the reference name of a further project and seedN is the subfolder there the "wind files" will be located. The overall tool I want to develop has a rather complex frame, but your answer will be helpful.

Comment: Investigate the function `fullfile` for building file names with paths to suit your requirements.